# How can i access the cellcontentclick property from my Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to do a DataGrid where i can change rows with buttons in every row. One is the edit button and one is the delete button. Also I want that the addbutton is only in the last row where there is no content in the whole row.

I saw in the internet that you can change Rows if you go to datagrid Propertys and make CellContentClick event, but unfortunatly I can´t find such a Property when i click in my Datagrid.

XAML Code DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridUser" Visibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10,50,9,52" Grid.RowSpan="3" RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idUser" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="UsernameUser" Binding="{Binding Username}" Header="Username"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="IsAdminUser" Binding="{Binding IsAdmin}" Header="IsAdmin"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="+" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Click="AddUser_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Click="EditUser_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: screenshot]

This screenshot shows the visual datagrid. Is it possible how i drew it, that the addbutton is at a new row with no content only the button.

Also I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxeWaUwVMuo from 5:10 he shows exactly what i want to do.

I also read something about DataGridView, can it be that you can only use the CellContentClick there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have an addbutton in a new row with no content only the button depends how you are planning to add row.

CellContentClick is only available for DataGridView.
You can enable DataGrid CellClick By writing some style. Like this, <Style x:Key="Cell" TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridHeader_MouseDoubleClick"/>
</Style>

Comment: Hi shisin, i figured out that it would be better if add button is not in the datagrid else extern button. Do i have to copie the style and paste it in the <DataGrid><DataGrid/>? Because it shows that Key can only be used on a tag contained in an IDictionary type property and TargetType is not supported in a WPF project

Comment: You can define this style in Window.Resources section. It works like dictionary.

Comment: I changed my xaml as you said. I tried to follow the steps from the YT-video i linked in my Question now and it doesnt show me the ColumnIndex. Is this new Dictionary restricted?

Comment: The above code was to add clickable event to your cell. I am not getting your problem w.r.t. ColumnIndex. Elaborate on that please.

Comment: How can I use the clickable event in an if() in my Windows code, i have the buttons in every row to click on, do i have to do a clickevent for the buttons in the datagrid or for the do i have to do the clickevent for the whole datagrid and reference on the delete button or edit button?

Comment: It's really confusing, what you are trying to ask. Your question is not clear. If you are using  clickevent of button to delete or edit a row then you need not use the above code for clicking a cell.

Comment: Sry if i am confusing a bit with my unclear question... what i want to do is exact the same as in the YT-Video i linked in my Question above, if click on delete button, i want that the row where i clicked the delete button should be deleted and if i click on the edit button, i should be allowed to edit the user from this row. What do i need for these things. ALso thank you for trying hard to help me with the problem, i am new in this programming world...

Comment: Just check that if you are able to hit a function after Delete Click. And get the id of that row and delete the row manually and update the dataGridView as well. If you dont update datagrid then your changes won't reflect.